# system() call returns "Permission Denied" on Windows XP

Tags: c, windows, windows-xp

I am experiencing a problem with a C program running on Windows XP that is getting Permission Denied (EACCES) errors when it tries to call system().

It doesn't seem to matter what I put in the command string, the commands all work manually but get Permission Denied errors when executed via system()

The other interesting thing is that the program works correctly on other XP machines, just not this one. That makes it feel like some kind of OS setting, but I am not totally sure what system() does under the hood and would like to understand what is happening here.

Here is my test code:

```
fprintf( stderr, "DEBUG: Running test of system(NULL) call...\n" );
if ( ( ret = system( NULL ) ) != 0)
    fprintf( stderr, "  DEBUG: ret: %d: errno: %d, %s\n", ret, errno, strerror( errno ) );

fprintf( stderr, "DEBUG: Running test of system(\"sleep 1\") call...\n" );
if ( ( ret = system( "sleep 1" ) ) != 0 )
    fprintf( stderr, "  DEBUG: ret: %d: errno: %d, %s\n", ret, errno, strerror( errno ) );
```

This produces an output of

```
DEBUG: Running test of system(NULL) call...
  DEBUG: ret: 1: errno: 0, No error
DEBUG: Running Test of system("sleep 1") call...
  DEBUG: ret: -1: errno: 13, Permission denied
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: I have also modified my code to use CreateProcess() instead of system(), and I still get an "Access Denied" error (5). This makes it sound even more like an OS setting, but I don't know where to look.

UPDATE2: Process Monitor shows the failure in a call to "QueryOpen" for the path "D:\cmd.exe", which does not exist. All the other calls are for C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, so I don't know why the one call is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved, the problem turned out to be a anti-virus service running in the background that was somehow interfering with things.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your program with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?  Process Monitor will show you all of the system calls your program makes, plus lots of other metadata about the calls (such as their arguments and their return values).  It can help you debug why you're getting the "Permission Denied" error.

Comment: I'll have to experiment with that a little bit and see if I get any more information.

Comment: Ok, so after running process monitor, the issue appears to be one call to QueryOpen on "D:\cmd.exe", which does not exist. All the other system calls are to the normal C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, so I don't know what would make it look in the wrong place.

Comment: @bde: Is your `%PATH%` environment variable set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're checking for failure correctly?  [MSDN doesn't list EACCES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273022%28VS.60%29.aspx) as a possible failure.  EACCES could simply be in errno from previous code.

```
int how_to_test_system(char const* command) {
  int rc;
  switch ((rc = system(command))) {
  case -1: // an error happened in calling system() itself
    perror("system"); // prints "system: <msg>"
    break;

  case 0: // command completed successfully
    break;

  default: // command executed, but had a non-zero return code
    // you might want to log something here
    // (otherwise you can simplify this switch into a single if for -1)
    break;
  }
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: The error is coming from the case where the command was executed, but had a non-zero return code. From MSDN "If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter," I think this is how I am getting the EACCES error. I can try system(NULL) and see if that works.

Comment: @bde: The return code of the executed program doesn't have to be an errno constant; what it means depends on the exact program executed, except that zero mean "success" and non-zero means "some kind of failure".  Do you have a short test case? (Update the question text with it.)

Comment: @Roger, I was wrong before, I see what you mean. I updated the question with a test case that illustrates what I am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

COMSPEC environment variable is not set properly or is being overridden

Look for COMSPEC in
1. Built-in system variables

2. System variables found in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive
3. Local variables found in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive
4. All environment variables and paths set in the Autoexec.bat file
5. All environment variables and paths set in a logon script (if present)
6. Variables used interactively in a script or batch file

The real meat of how this works is here...
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I agree that it does appear that the COMSPEC environment variable is being overridden, but typing "echo %COMSPEC%" in the environment where I am running my process shows "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", which appears to be correct. How would COMSPEC be overridden if it is correct in the shell the process is created from?

Comment: @bde That is if you are logged in as yourself - you say above you are running as system.
a) Check the value from system
b) make sure you are not overriding COMSPEC in 3,4 or 5 above